# Classification of custom objects

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I need to write a program that, given an object with certain attributes, it knows how to classify it. It should know how to classify new objects by being trained with a list of known objects with known attributes.

For example, I have object `A` with the following attributes: `a=10` and `b=1`. I also trained the program so that it knows that values between `5..15` for `a` and `0..2` for `b` classify the given object as `label1`.

As the program evolves, I need to further train it with known data so that the attribute intervals will get more accurate (hence the classification).

Now, I haven't got any experience with machine learning or any of this kind and I would like to know how should I start with this. I've seen plenty of tutorials, but only for text classification. And only for 2-ways classification (that is, positive or negative, yes or no...only two values to choose from). I would have 5-6 labels to start with and their number will soon increase. Also, the object attributes are integers.

Any tip is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machine learning is a *very* broad field, so the first step would be knowing exactly what you're looking for and familiarizing yourself with the subproblem you're trying to solve.

By your description, you're trying to solve a [**classification problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) in a [**supervised learning**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) approach.

I'll paraphrase a bit from [here](https://github.com/goncalopp/simple-ocr-opencv):

---

The classification problem consists in identifying to which class a observation belongs to.

Supervised learning is a way of "teaching" a machine. Basically, an algorithm is trained through examples (i.e.: this particular object belongs to class X). After training, the machine should be able to apply its aquired knowledge to new data.

The [k-NN algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_classification) is one of the simplest algorithms for solving this kind of problem. I suggest you familiarize yourself with it.

---

You have an implementation of k-NN in scipy. [Here's a link to a tutorial on using it](https://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/scikit-learn/index.html#k-nearest-neighbors-classifier).

Now, answering your specific questions:

> only for 2-ways classification (that is, positive or negative, yes or
>   no...only two values to choose from)

k-NN can handle any (finite) number of classes, so you're clear

> Also, the object attributes are integers

K-NN usually uses a continuous space - so you'll have to convert those to floats.

**Mapping the attributes values into points in the algorithm space is not a trivial problem** (see [Data pre-processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_pre-processing), especially the articles on normalization, feature extraction and selection)

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints! It's the kind of help I was looking for.